# Python try: ing not to repeat code. try: except and else

Tags: python, python-2.7, web2py, try-except

I have this:

```
try:    
    if session.var:
        otherVar = session.var
    else:
        util = db.utility[1]
        otherVar = session.var = util.freshOutTheBank
except AttributeError:
    util = db.utility[1]
    otherVar = session.var = util.freshOutTheBank

...do stuff with otherVar
```

The case is that the session.var might not exist or could be None. This code is also run more than once by a user during a session.

How do I avoid repeating the code. I basically want to do an 'except and else' or am I looking at this incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a web2py `session` object, note that it is an instance of `gluon.Storage`, which is like a dictionary with two exceptions: (1) keys can be accessed like properties, and (2) accessing a non-existent key/property returns `None` rather than raising an exception. So, you can simply do something like:

```
otherVar = session.var = session.var if session.var else db.utility[1].freshOutTheBank
```

Note, if you want to distinguish between non-existent keys and keys that have an explicit value of `None`, you cannot use `hasattr(session, 'var')`, as that will return `True` even if there is no `'var'` key. Instead, you can check `session.has_key('var')`, which will return `False` if there is no `'var'` key.

Comment: I am so sure I ended up in this position because there was an AttributeError being thrown and I was trying to deal with it. However, I have changed the code to a simply if-else and it's working even on login when the variable hasn't been set. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid using `session.var` if it doesn't exist by checking for it first, using `hasattr`. This avoids the need for the `try`/`except` block all together.

```
if hasattr(session, 'var') and session.var is not None:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

An alternative might be to have the `else` in your original code just `raise` an exception to get to the `except` block, but it's sort of ugly:

```
try:
    if session.var:
        ...
    else:
        raise AttributeError
except AttributeError:
    ...
```

In this situation, I think the "Look Before you Leap" style of programming (using `hasattr`) is nicer than the usually more Pythonic style of "Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission" (which uses exceptions as part of flow control). But either one can work.

If your code was compartmentalized into smaller functions, it might be even easier to deal with the issue. For instance, if you wrote a `get_session_var` function, it could `return` from the successful case (inside the `try` and `if` blocks), and the two error cases could be resolved later:

```
def get_session_var(session):
    try:
        if session.var:
            return session.var
    except AttributeError:
        pass

    util = db.utility[1]
    session.var = util.freshOutTheBank
    return session.var
```

Comment: Or `if getattr(session, 'var', None) is not None`, to fuse the existence/None checks.

Comment: As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53352100/440323), `hasattr(session, 'var')` is not necessary with the web2py `session` object, as it will simply return `None` for a non-existent key/property rather than raising an exception.

Comment: I was trying to avoid checking. Going with the Duck-Typing concept.